# Are these sentences grammatically correct in e-mail?

Tags: definite-article

Are these sentences grammatically correct in e-mail?

> I saw your catalogue of 'Canadian Used Car & Truck Values' and I can't find my vehicle. Therefore, I have a question. How much is value of my car?
>   -- Information of my car --

This information is sorely needed for me.

Answer (score 1):

Close. Just add an article for "value" and double quotes unless you are already in a quotation.

> I saw your catalogue of "Canadian Used Car & Truck Values" and I can't find my vehicle. Therefore, I have a question. How much is **the** value of my car?

BTW, "This information is sorely needed **by** me."

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, I would ask: WHAT is the value of my car? -or- HOW MUCH is my car worth?

Answer (score 0):

> [Greeting],
>
> I saw your catalogue of "Canadian Used Car & Truck Values," but I
>   wasn't able to find my vehicle. It's a [2002 AwesomeMobile]. Is there
>   a listing for this vehicle that I missed? Could you please tell me the
>   value of my car? I really need this information.
>
> - Year: 2002
> - Make: AwesomeMotors
> - Model: AwesomeMobile
> - Style: 2-door
> - Mileage: 5.
>
> Thank you,
>
> [Name]

For the most part the original would be understandable & fine, with minor alterations.

I changed "and" to "but" in the first sentence - you looked, but couldn't find it as expected. I also changed "can't find" to past tense. This works either way though.

I'd say there's no need to state that you have a question - it's obvious when you ask one.

Including the vehicle info in the body text is optional, but makes it clear up front what car you're looking for.

I would ask for the value and for help looking elsewhere for the information I need. Also, there may be a difference between "trade-in value" (to a dealer as part of buying a new car) and "resale value" if you want to sell it yourself.

"Sorely needed" sounds very British to me, so I personally wouldn't use that - perhaps it's a regional thing. I'd also suggest using an 'active' rather than 'passive' construction for that sentence:

> "I really need this information" vs. "This information is really needed by me (sounds wrong)."

(Aside: if you really need the car value, you could check [Kelley Blue Book online](http://www.kbb.com/) which is primarily for U.S. values, but you can check border areas near Canada).